# Testear compras integradas en android

Tags: android

Tengo la app publicada en alpha cerrada con 10 cuentas de email.
He probado a descargar la app en modo tester con diferentes cuentas y en todas me cobran por realizar el pago.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Al principio cuando no tenía la app subida a alpha me dejaba realizar el pago en modo test y no me cobraban.

Comment: Tienes que ejecutar tu app en un móvil que tenga como cuenta principal una de tus 10 cuentas de tester.

Comment: ya lo he hecho @diegoveloper, pero me han cobrado el micropago xD lo tengo en alfa cerrado, me hice tester con una de esas cuentas y aún así me cobran :\

Comment: Hmm si tienes instalada la misma versión que tienes en alpha, y si en la consola > account details > License Testing , tienes agregado los correos de test además de usar el móvil con cuenta principal una de las que tienes de test no debería cobrarte, al momento de pagar te sale que estás en modo TEST.

Comment: ciertamente eso me salía al principio (creo que cuando subí la versión a alpha lo de test dejó de aparecer) ahora no sale nada de test

Comment: Important: After you publish your app to an alpha or beta channel, your testers need to opt-in to your app's alpha or beta test using the provided opt-in URL before they can make test purchases. Note: License test accounts must be on the user's Android device.

Comment: @pcg26 ¿estas seguro que el cobro se realizó?, como has comprobado esto del lado de tu tarjeta de credito o tarjeta Google Play?

Comment: @Jorgesys ha llegado el recibo de paypal, y en la cuenta de desarrollador aparece como ingresos dicha compra